# Nested ng-include not working when element containing the ng-include attribute is itself added using ng-include attribute in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

[Please check this demo plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/71Nudes4eTbz1RBX9gsb) to understand my problem better.

In my main page I've a table. Each table row is followed by an empty row which is hidden initially. When clicked on first row, I am injecting html within the empty row below it using directive

**Main Page Index.html:**

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="student in Students" class="rowDirctive">
   <td>{{student.FirstName}}</td>
   <td>{{student.LastName}}</td>
</tr>
<!--Empty row-->
<tr class="empty-row" style="display:none" id="{{student.Id}}" ng-repeat-end>
   <td colspan="2"></td>
</tr>
```

**Directive** used for injecting html on click of first row:

```
    appRoot.directive('rowDirctive', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        replace: false,
        link: function (scope, element) {
            element.bind("click", function () {
                var rowId = "#"+scope.student.Id;
                var innerhtml = angular.element($compile('<span class="" ng-include="\'_StudentDetailsTabs.html\'">' +
                                '</span>')(scope));

                if ($(rowId + " td span").length === 0) {
                    $(rowId + " td").html(innerhtml);
                }

                if ($(rowId).is(':hidden')) {
                    $(rowId).slideDown("slow");
                } else {
                    $(rowId).slideUp("slow");

                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Now when click on first row, the span is included within the empty row which itself contains **ng-include="_StudentDetailsTabs.html"**. The _StudentDetailsTabs.html partial is included properly, I've no issue with it. But the _StudentDetailsTabs.html partial itself contains another three ng-include attributes which are not working.

**_StudentDetailsTabs.html:**

```
   <tabset>
       <tab heading="Personal Details" ng-click="PersonalDetails()">
          <span ng-include="_PersonalDetails.html"  ng-controller="StudentDetailsCtrl"></span>
       </tab>
       <tab heading="Educational Details" ng-click="EducationalDetails()">
          <span ng-include="_EducationalDetails.html" ng-controller="StudentDetailsCtrl"></span>
       </tab>
    </tabset>
  <br><br>
  <span ng-include="_OtherDetails.html" ng-controller="StudentDetailsCtrl"></span>
```

Now when the above partial **_StudentDetailsTabs.html** is included into the empty row, why the ng-includes within it (_StudentDetailsTabs.html) not working. Why its not including the partials?

**Edit:** [Here is the demo plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/71Nudes4eTbz1RBX9gsb).  Now I don't know why, when I created this plunker the **_StudentDetailsTabs.html** is also not being included.

Comment: There should be no problem with nested in-includes. The problem is probably somewhere else. Could you post a plunker with your not-working example?

Comment: here is the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/71Nudes4eTbz1RBX9gsb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ng-includes are wrong, they should be with quotes, as in you should be passing a string

> ngInclude | string
>   angular expression evaluating to URL. If the source is a string constant, make sure you wrap it in single quotes, e.g. src="'myPartialTemplate.html'".

so you need to change

```
<span ng-include="_PersonalDetails.html"  ...></span>
```

to

```
<span ng-include="'_PersonalDetails.html'"  ...></span>
```

and so on

Comment: There is something else that is wrong too then. Can you look into the plunkr so it matches your current problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your plunker reads `<span ng-include="'/_FileName.html'">`. It should read `<span ng-include="'_FileName.html'">`, without those forward slashes.